# .Net MVC how to add scripts to individual views

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was wondering if there is a way to add JavaScript files to individual views if I am using a wrapper `.cshtml` file.

Basically I have a wrapper cshtml file called `_Layout` that I am using for all my front end views. It basically has the `<header>` section and the HTML for my header/navigation and the footer. It also contains references to all the JavaScript files I need on each page after the footer.

However, on my contact view I want to use another JavaScript file, but I don't want to add it to the wrapper as that will add it to every single view.

Is there anyway to get add the file to the wrapper using a conditional statement - i.e. if Contact view then reference the contact JS file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Razor's `section`. It allows you to create "sections" in your layout page, and then add to them from your view pages.

You might already have a section "Scripts" declared in your layout page. If not, all you need to do is add `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` in your layout, immediately after your other `script` tags. This creates a section called "Scripts" which we will add to later.

Then, you can add to that section by adding the following to your individual views:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
}
```

You can do this with other elements as well; you aren't limited only to scripts. You'll just have to add another `@RenderSection("SectionName", required: false)` to your layout page.

You might also be interested in reading Scott Gu's slightly dated (2010) [blog post on Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor).